# Replace the first characters if the object contain the symbol Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the string objects in the pandas Dataframe:

```
['10/2014', '2014','9/2013']
```

How to replace them to get this result:

```
['2014','2014','2013']
```

Comment: This is far from a [mcve]... What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the desired string

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'co1':['10/2014', '2014','9/2013']})
df.co1.str.replace("^[\w]*/","") # pass in the pattern you want to replace
```

Output

```
0    2014
1    2014
2    2013
```

Comment: If you have any article about using "^[\w]*" - it will be awesome!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the last set of characters separated by `'/'`, try this :

```
[k.split('/')[-1] for k in ['10/2014', '2014','9/2013']]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
['2014', '2014', '2013']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(['10/2014', '2014','9/2013'])

a[0].str[-4:]
```

This will keep the last 4 characters

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function which deals with splitting the values (if necessary) and the use `apply` against the column you want to format:

Assuming the following df:

```
raw_data = {'col0': ['1', '2', '3'],
            'col1': ['10/2014', '2014','9/2013']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['col0', 'col1'])
```

We can do:

```
def splitter(df):
  try:
    df = df.split('/')[1]
  except IndexError:
    pass
  return df

df = df['col1'].apply(splitter)
```

Output:

```
0   2014
1   2014
2   2013
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dft = pd.DataFrame(['10/2014', '2014','9/2013'], columns=['date'])
dft['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dft['date']) # Convert column with string to datetime
dft['date'] = dft['date'].dt.year.astype(str) # Convert the integer year back to string
```

gives:

```
0    2014
1    2014
2    2013
Name: date, dtype: object
```